# Spring Security: Show warning before overwriting session

Tags: java, spring, security, session, spring-security

I have set max concurrent sessions to one. 
Now there are `2 situations` I want to handle if there is an active session (Someone is already logged in for that User Id):

1. If the user accesses login page again on the same browser:
   In this case, he will be directly logged in.
2. If the user logs in from different browser/client machine: In this case, need to show the error "A session is already active for this user. Are you sure you want to overwrite the session?". If the user selects 'yes', the error will be shown at the previous session (this I know error page can be configured), and if he selects no, it will not login, the previous session will persist.

How can these usecases be achieved using spring security? So far, I have been able to found the basic management of concurrent sessions, by setting max session count and error page.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have almost done it. To ask user before overwriting a session follow the below steps.

1. The expiredUrl property of ConcurrentSessionFilter should got to a page where the UI is provided to ask user (e.g. askUser.html).
2. The askUser.html form submits to another url (e.g. /api/confirmSessionRewrite) with POST parameter yes or no.
3. In controller ConfirmSessionRewrite either remove the user from session registry or forward it to login page.

   `sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(info.getSessionId());`
4. You have to modify your config so that the ConcurrentSessionFilter would not run on /api/confirmSessionRewrite request. Otherwise it will be a loop.